# OpenCv IP camera connection

Tags: c++, opencv

Error: 
"warning: Error opening file(../../modules/highgui/src/opencv cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:545)"

I am trying to access mobile camera via IP in OpenCV Visual Studio in C++.
Having this error.
Anyone Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code, how are you trying to open IP camera? This message means that URL is incorrect

Comment: main{
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;
    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://USER:PWD@IPADDRESS:8088/mjpeg.cgi?user=USERNAME&password=PWD&channel=0&.mjpg";
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }   
}

Comment: and I tried another one, Have a look please:

Comment: int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;
    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://<username:password>@<ip_address>/video.cgi?.mjpg";
    //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;}
    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
       }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }   
}

Comment: do not write code in comments - edit your answer. And check the connection URL with VLC player and ffpmpeg, if both works - problem in your program

Comment: can you please elaborate? which connection do you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue  which cause this error is **"username"** and **"password"**.
When I removed **"username"** and **"password"** from **IP Webcam(mobile application)**. Then this work smoothly and I get video on my laptop **(Visual studio C++)**.

Comment: If this is the answer, you presumably know it is correct, in which case you should accept it. If it is not an answer, you should copy the text of it and click `edit` under your original question and add it in there as further information - then delete this *"answer"*.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer of my question.